# How to print a specific column to a file if condition seen in multiple files?

Tags: text-processing, awk, columns

I have a bunch of files (totally 2181 files; `anacovis2_1_summary_betai_reg.out` ~ `anacovis2_2181_summary_betai_reg.out`) like below:

```
anacovis2_2_summary_betai_reg.out
anacovis2_3_summary_betai_reg.out
anacovis2_4_summary_betai_reg.out
anacovis2_5_summary_betai_reg.out
anacovis2_6_summary_betai_reg.out
anacovis2_7_summary_betai_reg.out
.
.
.
anacovis2_2179_summary_betai_reg.out
anacovis2_2180_summary_betai_reg.out
anacovis2_2181_summary_betai_reg.out
```

and each file looks like this:

```
 COVARIABLE MRK M_Pearson SD_Pearson BF(dB) Beta_is SD_Beta_is eBPis
  1       1    -0.00974041     0.21914544   -10.86437924    -0.00058189     0.00694111     0.03003007
  1       2     0.08603974     0.19711939    -1.27963044     0.00381909     0.00953539     0.16192245
  1       3    -0.02912035     0.20260353   -12.60498743    -0.00146066     0.00633105     0.08749265
```

I want to go through each file (1 to 2181) and if the first column (COVARIABLE) is equal to "1" print only the last column and save it in a separate file (I want to save the output of each file in a seperate file).

How do I do this in `awk` or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be done easily with `awk` only.

```
awk '($1==1){print $NF>FILENAME"_new"}' anacovis2_{1..2181}_summary_betai_reg.out
```

This will check if the first column was equal with 1 `$1==1` then print the last column `$NF` into the new file with format of same FILENAME but ends with `_new`, so the output files would be `FILENAME_new`.

To reading all 2181 files, we used [brace expansion parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) here.

Comment: related to your next question you can save to one file if you want merge these files finally, like `awk '($1==1){print $NF>"one_file"}' input{1..2181}`  :    )

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is:

```
for((i=1;i<2182;i++)); do
    file_in="anacovis2_${i}_summary_betai_reg.out"
    file_out="awk_output_${i}"
    awk '$1==1 { print $NF }' "$file_in" >"$file_out"
done
```

A faster solution may be to open the input and output files witin `awk` so that only one `awk` process is needed instead of 2181...